# HIVE SQL - JOIN

Tags: join, hive

I am trying to perform a left join between tables. The syntax looks something like this:

```
select a.x1, a.x2, a.x3, b.y1 from a left join b on a.x1=b.x1
```

Ideally, the query should give all records that are present in A. However, I am missing out records wherever there is a **null value in variable a.x1**.

While I can circumvent the problem by writing a separate code that caters to null values only, and then performing a union, I was wondering if there is a way to do so with the join itself.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you miss such rows. Then it's a bug. You should report it. Unless your query is different than what you show here.

Comment: @ypercube: I do have additional conditions in the where clause but here's the thing, if I simply run my query on table A without joining with B keeping the where conditions intact, I do see null values in variable a.x1. As soon as I put the join in place, the nulls get automatically dropped.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show the actual queries?